# Typescript derive return type from inherited method

Tags: typescript

Let's say we have WrapperClass

```
export abstract class WrapperClass {
  protected abstract childMethod(): unknown;

  wrapperMethod(): unknown {
    const result = this.childMethod();
    return result;
  }
}
```

ChildClass

```
export class ChildClass extends WrapperClass {
  protected childMethod(): ChildResponse {
    const response = new ChildResponse();
    return response;
  }
}
```

I want typescript to automatically determine that `response` is of type `ChildResponse` when I do this:

```
const childClass = new ChildClass();
const response = childClass.wrapperMethod();
console.log(response.id);
```

Comment: Can you use a generic like `WrapperClass<T>`, `childMethod(): T`?

Comment: @Marty Solution using generics also works. But I am not sure how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [generic type parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-classes) when defining the wrapper class, so that every child class would be required to define a return type for the child method:

```js
export abstract class WrapperClass<ChildResponseType> {
  protected abstract childMethod(): ChildResponseType;

  wrapperMethod(): ChildResponseType {
    const result = this.childMethod();
    return result;
  }
}
```

Then pass the response type when defining the child class:

```js
export class ChildClass extends WrapperClass<ChildResponse> {
  protected childMethod() {
    const response = new ChildResponse();
    return response;
  }
}
```

See this [link for a Typescript sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAQwEYGcZQQY3pgNglFOAdQzDGCgGF9CAeKgCwEtcATAJWBUgDsVgAFQCeFAHxwA3gCg4cMFAgxg2YG0Sp0WHC3YBZYDEYQ2ACgCUALjhNWnbnwEiKAbmmy4AdzIUoBoyYW1rbsXDwQ-EKiwFIecpgRaHBQ3ACuuPAAvHBGzCgAdJi6bP7GZuZucnIpMKlQvMlpGZVwAL7S7dJ4BEQh9uGRsVVwzGzWaFDMvADmLfGJ6KnY0BZDw1W5BaNw2QDkKBAAtsAAtKO7cW0d7qCQsHDdhDbFND1woMq8bESkCOSUr3ofTCjmAEhkcgUShUynURTspUC5jW8348BSAwEOzgvGAnmedhBiWAFjmjVq9UamOALXanQSaIeL1oRGyuPxfUBKFJXQWVNB2Ph7C5+W8f18iPKbgZB1wwHyuAg01MGNB+VGFWkQA) with an example.